# Почему после возвращения в исходное активити перестает работать кнопка?

Tags: java, android

Имеется такая схема MainActivity --> ActivityAbout.
Код MainActivity.class

```
public void onClickGo(View view) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityAbout.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Код ActiviyAbout.class

```
public void onClickBack(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityAbout.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

После возвращения из ActivityAbout в MainActivity перестает работать кнопка в главном активити. В чем может быть проблема?
Код самой кнопки

```
public void onClickStop(View view) {
        if (mediaPlayer == null)
            return;
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.stop:
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Попробуйте заменить интент во второй активити на `finish();`

Comment: @Соколов дело в том, что если оставить во втором активити `finish();`, то при нажатии кнопки "назад" - закрывается все приложение

Comment: Я не вижу в этом проблемы. Просто переопределите кнопку back в первой активити

Comment: Что значит перестаёт работать кнопка? Добавьте логирование при клике, чтобы убедится, что метод отрабатывает (или не отрабатывает).